# Remove duplicate python

Tags: apt, python

This morning I installed python3.3.2 from source, which is giving me some headaches, so now I want it removed. python3 launches python3.3.2, which is stored in /usr/local/bin. However, when I try to remove it, it wants to remove python3.3.1, stored in /usr/bin. I obviously want to keep this one.

```
$ which -a python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

How do I get 'sudo apt-install remove python3' to **not** remove the necessary 3.3.1 /usr/bin one, and only 3.3.2 one in /local/bin? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please update your question a bit. What about the topic "Remove self compiled python"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you sad: You have installed python from source. If you want to remove this exact version you just build your own, you can't use the package-system because your python is not registered in this.

If python is the only software you installed by source with `make install` then it should be save just to delete everything under */usr/local/* because that folder is just for you ;-) (more info regarding that folder can be found in the [File System Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) )

```
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/
```

**But** if you installed different software without the help of `apt`,`dpkg` or `aptitude`, that will be lost, too. Then this [Artikel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544656/1816482) on Stackoverflow may help you out, it mentions a way to remove python with the help of it's source.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I've still got a lot to learn about linux! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As a tipp: you can find the word *local* on even different places, most of the time it means the same like */usr/local/*.